# Microsoft Teams Connector development - Send feedback link not working in Configuration

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on a Microsoft Teams Connector and have created the app package.
I have sideloaded the Manifest.zip to my Team Configuration and everything seems to work fine.
The only thing, not working is the "Send feedback" url in the connector configuration. When I click that link, the only errormessage I receive is ":-(
Something went wrong."
I have gathered the URL with Fiddler and the URL being used is

/connectors/Feedback/%20Index?Client=SkypeSpaces&MailboxAddress=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx&Culture=de-de&HostName=teams.microsoft.com&iFrame=true&ProfileUniqueName=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&SSApiHost=emea-client-ss.msg.skype.com&SSThread=XXXXXXX

When I configure a connector, provided by another company, the URL gathered in Fiddler looks different, like /connectors/Content/ViewTemplate/feedback.html.

In the manifest I see no option to configure the feedback URL, neither I do in the Connector registration portal.

What configuration is necessary, to get the feedback URL working?

Comment: Is this question related to `botframework`?

Comment: It is not the botframework 100%, but the connector creation for teams on the microsoft explanations run (from my understanding) somehow under botframework

Comment: Connectors actually have nothing to do with Bot Framework. The implementations share some plumbing in common but are completely different (which is why, for example, @mentions don't work in Connectors.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. But what could be the reason for the problem with the feedback link?

Comment: I'm checking on this for you. It appears the "Send Feedback" link doesn't work for external connectors, but in that case it shouldn't appear at all.

Comment: I am a developer from Microsoft Connectors Team. Please drop a mail to o365connectorsupport@microsoft.com with manifest file, fiddler trace and screenshot of the page where you see the feedback link. We will look at the issue and get back to you.